# Looking for spark-core v3.3.2 RC date

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking for RC date of spark-core project v3.3.2 to mitigate CVE-2022-42889.

Thanks.

Referred https://spark.apache.org/versioning-policy.html which says maintenance release will be more frequent but it doesn't mention any time span.